# unix fork() understanding

Tags: linux, unix, fork

```
int main(){
    fork();
}
```

I know this is a newbie question, but my understanding is that the parent process now will fork a new child process exactly as the parent one, which means that the child should also fork a child process and so on... In reality, this only generates one child process. I cant understand what code will the child be executing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The child process begins executing at the exact point where the last one left off - after the fork statement. If you wanted to fork forever, you'd have to put it in a while loop.

Answer (score 4):

As everybody mentioned, the child also starts executing after `fork()` has finished. Thus, it doesn't call `fork` again.

You could see it clearly in the very common usage like this:

```
int main()
{
    if (fork())
    {
        // you are in parent. The return value of fork was the pid of the child
        // here you can do stuff and perhaps eventually `wait` on the child
    }
    else
    {
        // you are in the child. The return value of fork was 0
        // you may often see here an `exec*` command
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a semi-colon.

But the child (and also the parent) is continuing just after the `fork` happenned. From the point of view of application programming, `fork` (like all [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) is "atomic".

The only difference between the two processes (which after the `fork` have conceptually separate memory spaces) is the result of the `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

If the child went on to call `fork`, the child would have two `fork`s (the one that created it and the one that it then made) while the parent would only have one (the one that gave it a child). The nature of `fork` is that one process calls it and two processes return from it.